# show that $I+tT$ is bijective $t>0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

let $T\in L(H)$ such that $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$ show that $I+tT$ is bijective $t>0$.
how can i prove this using Lax milgram that i'm not familiar with.

Comment: The assumptions imply $\langle (I+tT)x,x\rangle =\langle Tx,x\rangle +t\|x\|^2\ge t\|x\|^2.$ Hence $(I+tT)x=0$ implies $x=0$ for $t>0.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc you prove injectivity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\langle (I+tT)x,x\rangle =\|x\|^2+t\langle Tx,x\rangle \ge \|x\|^2$$ Hence $I+tT$ is injective and its range is closed (see the spoiler).

> Indeed, let $(I+tT)x_n\to y.$ Then the sequence $(I+tT)x_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition. We have $$\langle (I+tT)(x_n-x_m),x_n-x_m\rangle \ge \|x_n-x_m\|^2$$ Thus $x_n$ satisfies the Cauchy condition. Let $x=\lim x_n.$ Then $(I+tT)x_n\to (I+tT)x.$ Therefore $y=(I+tT)x.$

On the other hand if $y\perp {\rm Im}\, (I+tT)$  then
$$0=\langle y, (I+tT)y\rangle \ge \|y\|^2$$ hence $y=0.$ Thus ${\rm Im}\, (I+tT)=\mathcal{H}.$